# Rename column in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am trying to rename a column in one table where data already exists.
But below is the error it is throwing.Please advice.

Syntax I tried

```
ALTER TABLE TPR.PRODUCT_FEATURE RENAME COLUMN PRODUCT_ID TO SERVICE_ID
```

Error:

> [Error] Script lines: 23-23 ------------------------
>    DROP, ALTER, TRANSFER OWNERSHIP, REVOKE, or CREATE OR REPLACE on object type "COLUMN" cannot be processed because there is an object "PRODUCT_FEATURE_X01", of type "PRIMARY KEY", which depends on it.. SQLCODE=-478, SQLSTATE=42893, DRIVER=3.67.28

Looks me to, I need to drop and recreate is the only option. Please advice.

Comment: Tip of today: always have s script file ready to easily re-create the database!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE TPR.PRODUCT_FEATURE 
    DROP CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_FEATURE_X01
```

Then alter your table:

```
ALTER TABLE TPR.PRODUCT_FEATURE RENAME COLUMN PRODUCT_ID TO SERVICE_ID
```

Then add new constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE TPR.PRODUCT_FEATURE
      ADD CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_FEATURE_X01
      PRIMARY KEY (insert,columns,here)
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I change the length and planning on adding new values to the same column (Varchar(5) to Varchar (20).  ALTER TABLE TPR.PRODUCT_FEATURE RENAME COLUMN PRODUCT_ID TO SERVICE_ID

Comment: You can do this (assuming you have already renamed it to SERVICE_ID) with `ALTER TABLE TPR.PRODUCT_FEATURE 
 ALTER COLUMN SERVICE_ID SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(20)`